# How to show that $(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))^{\times} \cong (\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}))^{\times}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

How to show that $$(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))^{\times} \cong (\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}))^{\times}$$ where $(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))^{\times}$ is multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.
Mapping $a+b\sqrt{2} \mapsto a+b\sqrt{3}$ is good for showing that additive group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is isomorphic with additive group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$. And  I showed that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ are not isomorphic. But for multiplicative part I couldn't find good mapping.

Comment: Do you know what these groups are abstractly? (For starters, do you know what $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ is abstractly?)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I don't think so. Could you write definition of abstractly group, maybe I heard it on my language (but, I don't think so)

Comment: Abstractly is an adverb, not an adjective. Qiaochu is wondering if you know a description of ${\bf Q}^\times$ that is amenable to being put to use in this problem (this is the basis of my hints).

Comment: @anon Sorry for English. I am not familiar with that description of $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ I heard we can show this (my question) using $(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))^{\times} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}))^{\times} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}[x]$ but I am not familiar with this. I am beginner at field theory. Sorry for English.

Comment: Don't worry about your English, you're doing fine. Those isomorphisms are in fact true, and are sort-of what my hint tries to get at. The $\bf Z$s in the middle though are redundant, and as an additive group I think it's be better to describe ${\bf Z}[x]$ as the free abelian group with coordinates indexed by the primes, i.e. for our purposes the direct sum $\bigoplus_p{\bf Z}$.

Comment: @anon I understand that $\{-1,1\} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and all invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ are like $\pm (1+\sqrt{2})^n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, so every $x \in (\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})^{\times}$ is like $x=(-1)^{l}(1+\sqrt{2})^{n}p_{i_{0}}^{\alpha_{0}}...p_{i_{k}}^{\alpha_{k}}$ for $l\in \{0,1\},\ n\in \mathbb{Z},  \alpha_{i}\in \mathbb{Z}$, and $\{(1+\sqrt{2})^n : n\in \mathbb{Z}\}\cong \mathbb{Z}$, so I have to prove that $p_{i_{0}}^{\alpha_{0}}...p_{i_{k}}^{\alpha_{k}} \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]$? I probably wrote something stupid...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints**:

- ${\bf Q}^\times\cong \{\pm1\}\times\bigoplus_p{\bf Z}$, where the $p$th coordinate is the power of $p$ in the prime factorization of a rational into positive/negative prime powers, and the sign is the rational's sign.
- Both ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{3})$ have unique factorization (or more precisely, their rings of integers)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Oops, yes. I think so, since it should be the direct product of torsion and free abelian just the same, right? (Since the quadratic extensions will be the fraction fields of their rings of integers, and the monoid of units in the ring of integers will be torsion times free abelian by unique factorization into primes.)